# How to search if multiple values exist in the table and all have the same value in another column?

Tags: php, sql, subquery

I'm looking to do something that is probably very simple to do but I can't formulate it and I don't really get help from Google. I basically have 3 tables in my db, one is `cocktails` (with id and value), one is `ingredients` (with id and value too) and one is `correspondences` (with id, cocktail ids and ingredient ids). This table basically reports what ingredient all cocktails have.

Through a form I'm given an array of ingredient ids in a `$_GET['ingredients']` variable.

I want to make a query in which I search for cocktails that I have enough ingredients to make.

I'm very sorry this is not very clear but I can't find any simpler way to describe my issue. Can any of you help me?

Comment: It's unclear what all those 'value's actually indicate. For `cocktails` it might possibly be irrelevant, for `ingredients` I'd assume the amount being available (if so, do name it `amount`) and if I understand the matter right `correspondences` is missing an `amount` column as well telling how much of the ingredient to use (or do you assume one unit for every ingredient?).

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks, well values are just the cocktail and the ingredient name. I don't ask for any kind of amount, as long as you have the ingredient I want it to consider that I can make it. I'm building this tool just so I can quickly know what cocktail I can make with whatever I have in my pantry.

Comment: Then still you do not know if ingredients are available – or do you intend to represent absence of ingredients by absence of an entry in the corresponding table? But if so, how would you then want to specify a recipe containing ingredients not available? There are no entries `correspondences` can refer to in the `ingredients` table then...

Comment: Assuming you add this `amount` column (or alternatively a boolean `available` column) then you might look up the cocktails available by e.g. `select cocktail_id from correspondences join ingredients on ingredient_id = ingredients.id group by cocktail_id having count(ingredient_id) = count(case when amount <> 0 then 1 end)`

Comment: If you add both amount columns to consider amounts in recipes, too, then this might work as well: `select distinct cocktail_id from correspondences c join ingredients i on ingredient_id = i.id group by cocktail_id, c.amount, i.amount having c.amount <= i.amount` – all queries untested, if you find an error please fix yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make a query in which I search for cocktails that I have enough ingredients to make.

We can phrase the logic with `not exists`: we want all cocktails that have no ingredients that do not belong to our list.

In SQL:

```
select *
from cocktails c
where not exists (
    select 1
    from correspondences r
    where 
        r.id_cocktail = c.id
        and r.id_ingredient not in (?, ?, ?)
)
```

This assumes that a cocktail always has at least one dependent row in `correspondences`.

The question marks represent the input list of ingredients, that you need to pass from your application.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll be testing this when I'm back home but I'm just wondering how can I make a PHP statement to pass the input list of ingredient IDs to the question marks, considering I don't know how many items will be in my list? Is there any way to pass an array in a prepared statement?